# Data is coming from db but not showing in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Hi m trying to fetch data from db, data is coming in dd(); but not showing in view table, m using laravel-5.8, thanks in advance, and m using the resource route for it.

Hi m trying to fetch data from db, data is coming in dd(); but not showing in view table, m using laravel-5.8, thanks in advance, and m using the resource route for it.

Controller:

```
      public function index()
      {
       $files = File::all();
        //dd($files);
        if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
        $file = Auth::user()->files;
        return view('home', compact('file', 'files'));
        } else {
        $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
        return view('layouts.master', $files);
       }

    $filedata = ($r->has('file') ? $query->wherefilename($r->filename) : $query)->get();

        $file = DB::table('importpdfs')->distinct('filename')->pluck('filename')
        ->reject(function($v) { return $v === 'Mean'; });

    return view('home', compact('files', 
  'filedata', 'importpdfs', 'data'))->withData(null);

    //return view('home', compact('files'))->withData(null);
    }
```

Blade file:

```
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="table_id">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th>File_ID</th>
                <th>Battery</th>

  <th>No_of_questions_attempted</th>
                <th>SAS</th>
                <th>NPR</th>
                <th>ST</th>
                <th>GR</th>
              </tr>
              @foreach ($files as $filedata)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $filedata->file_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->Battery }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->No_of_questions_attempted  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->SAS  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->NPR  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->ST  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->GR  }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody></table> 
          </div>


            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include partials.chartjs -->
  @include('partials.chartjs')
   <script type="text/javascript">
  window.svgPDF = () => {
  var svg  = 
  document.querySelector('#pie_chart svg'),
   xml  = new 
  XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
      data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml),
      img  = new Image()

      img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = 
    document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0 );
        window.chartPDF(canvas)
      }

        img.setAttribute('src', data)
      }
      </script>
```

How can i solve this? Or any suggestion or any link to tackle this issue??

Comment: have you tried using `return view('home')->with('files', $files)->with('filedata', $filedata);`?

Comment: Still same error

Comment: This Html code in your homw Page or not?

Comment: Yea it is in home page and data is also showing in dd();

Comment: Are you using dd() in home.blade.php and data is aslo showing in dd().

Answer (score 0):

Which blade file you print in post it's home.blade.php or layouts/master.blade.php ?
and send variable with "with" function or "compact" function on your else case you haven't copmact

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
      {
       $files = File::all();

        if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
        $file = Auth::user()->files;
        return view('home', compact('file', 'files'));
        } else {
        $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
        return view('layouts.master', $files);
       }

    $filedata = ($r->has('file') ? $query->wherefilename($r->filename) : $query)->get();

        $file = DB::table('importpdfs')->distinct('filename')->pluck('filename')
        ->reject(function($v) { return $v === 'Mean'; });

    return view('home', compact('files','filedata','importpdfs'));


    }
```

Comment: Use either with() or compact() function to load multiple array on view. don't think their is function  ->withData(null);

Comment: i just add separate solution for your problem

Answer (score 0):

**Your are using resource route**

When creating controller through php artisan. Laravel create few default function i.e index,create,store,show,edit,update,destroy

**example**

// app/routes.php

```
Route::resource('nerds', 'NerdController');
```

Actions Handled By the Controller

```
**HTTP Verb       Path (URL)          Action (Method)   Route Name**

GET               /nerds                 index          nerds.index
GET               /nerds/create          create         nerds.create
POST              /nerds                 store          nerds.store
GET               /nerds/{id}            show           nerds.show
GET               /nerds/{id}/edit       edit           nerds.edit
PUT/PATCH         /nerds/{id}            update         nerds.update
DELETE            /nerds/{id}            destroy        nerds.destroy
```

This will automatically assign many actions to that resource controller. Now if you, go to your browser and view your application at example.com/nerds, it will correspond to the proper method in your NerdController.

**The Views**
Since only four of our routes are GET routes, we only need four views. In our app/views folder, let's make those views now.

- app
- views

  - nerds

    - index.blade.php
    - create.blade.php
    - show.blade.php
    - edit.blade.php

In Your Controller

// app/controllers/NerdController.php

...

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
  public function index()
  {
     $files = File::all();

      if (Auth::user()->admin == 0) {
         $file = Auth::user()->files;
         return view('nerds.index', compact('file', 'files'));

       } else {
          $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
          return view('nerds.index', $files);
       }

       $filedata = ($r->has('file') ? $query->wherefilename($r->filename)
```

:$query)->get();

```
        $file = DB::table('importpdfs')->distinct('filename')->pluck('filename')
          ->reject(function($v) { return $v === 'Mean'; });

       return view('nerds.index', compact('files', 'filedata', 'importpdfs', 'data'));


}
```

Your view

// app/views/nerds/index.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="table_id">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th>File_ID</th>
                <th>Battery</th>

  <th>No_of_questions_attempted</th>
                <th>SAS</th>
                <th>NPR</th>
                <th>ST</th>
                <th>GR</th>
              </tr>
              @foreach ($files as $filedata)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $filedata->file_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->Battery }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->No_of_questions_attempted  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->SAS  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->NPR  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->ST  }}</td>
                <td>{{ $filedata->GR  }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody></table> 
          </div>


            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include partials.chartjs -->
  @include('partials.chartjs')
   <script type="text/javascript">
  window.svgPDF = () => {
  var svg  = 
  document.querySelector('#pie_chart svg'),
   xml  = new 
  XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
      data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml),
      img  = new Image()

      img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = 
    document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0 );
        window.chartPDF(canvas)
      }

        img.setAttribute('src', data)
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: same issue,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,m using the default home.blade.php https://ibb.co/gDcJ8N9   my routes are https://ibb.co/LkFy621   and when i use dd in controller then output is:  https://ibb.co/yhPXc9S